# Laravel Pagination One Model At A Time

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

How do you paginate only one collection on a page? Let me explain.

My controller has 2 calls to the database:

```
$users = User::whereAvailable(1)->paginate(10);
$cars = Cars::whereAvailable(1)->paginate(10);
```

In my view i have 2 tabs to display their respective results and a

`{!! $users->render() !!}` under one tab and `{!! $cars->render() !!}` for the other tab. If I go to cars and click next page, the paginator goes to the next page on both of the models.

My question is how do I only go to the next page on one of the models at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$pageName` parameter in your `paginate()` function:

https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate

`$users = User::whereAvailable(1)->paginate(10, ['*'], 'userPage');
$cars = Cars::whereAvailable(1)->paginate(10, ['*'], 'carPage');`

This will make them each use their own query parameter

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed! Thank you for the help, you saved me a lot of time and frustration.